# Quickly read million records from sql server using stored procedure and write it to csv using java and spring boot

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, stored-procedures, spring-batch

We have a stored procedure that is used to select a million records. The stored procedure looks something like below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ABC(@CustID varchar(20))
AS
BEGIN

WITH temporaryTable as (SELECT ab,bc,... FROM Table); // a very huge select query

SELECT a,b, ..., l FROM temporaryTable OUTER JOIN(some_table1)...  union all SELECT m,n,..., z FROM temporaryTable OUTER JOIN(some_table2); // two very huge select query with union

END
```

I have been tasked to fetch the result using that stored procedure and write it in a CSV file using java and spring boot.

I have tried the **spring-data-jpa's @NamedStoredProcedureQuery** way for fetching the result and write it into CSV using **opencsv** but this is too slow. I did use **setFirstResult() & setMaxResult()** methods but couldn't see any difference(*maybe this requires stored procedure to be configured differently, not sure though.*)

Right now I am trying to use **Spring Batch's StoredProcedureItemReader**(still configuring...) for reading the data and **FlatFileItemWriter** to write into CSV, but I am new to this and not sure whether this will help or not though I think that this link(https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/scalability.html#scalability) might help.

What I need is a direction where I can get the desired result.

Thanks and as always any helpful gesture from the community will be highly appreciated!!!

Comment: Is it mandatory to use a stored procedure ? If not you can copy data to a temporary table and do chunk base processing using spring boot batch's task executor (multi-threading) ?

Comment: I would restructure this so that your union all happens separately from the join to the temporary table.  It will give you a small bump in performance ( my execution plan showed about 8% )
Being that you are looking to create a csv, I would do this using BCP and powershell over Java and Spring.

SELECT a,b
FROM temporaryTable tt
JOIN(
SELECT a,b ...
FROM some_table1
UNION ALL 
SELECT a,b ...
FROM some_table2
) st ON tt.a = st.a AND tt.b = st.b

Comment: @dbbri - I will try your suggestion with DBA. As for BCP and powershell option, I did glanced over it but it might not work in my case as the program intended user's will be able to download the program as an ..exe file and then run it in their local.

Comment: @TechGuy - Yes, I have to use stored procedure. If I copy the data into a temporary table doesn't that add up the time ??
Having a Step with chunk based processing and multi-threading taskExecutor in a Job is what interested me in exploring Spring Batch but till now I am able to get the desired result.

Comment: Copying data shouldn't take much time. You should try this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would instead just use a Reader->Writer step with `JdbcCursorItemReader` for your Reader and `FlatFileItemWriter` for your Writer.

The Reader's sql would simply be your `SELECT` from your question. And the Writer would use `DelimitedLineAggregator` to create your CSV output.

Comment: Hi Dean,

Thanks for suggesting this approach but I would like to use Stored Procedure instead as this is what is used in our production also it will be unmaintainable to use sql from stored procedure directly in the long run.
I would first like to exhaust all my with the stored procedure and if this doesn't work then I will sit with my DBA to work out a solution as suggested in the comments above by @Tech Guy and then include your approach with some modification.

Comment: Alternately you could create an ItemReader that wraps your Stored Procedure. The read() method could just iterate over the result set that comes back from it. This would allow you better-fit the framework and make restartability easier to implement.